# I get a list is not callable error near the bottom of my code where it says ball.append, but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program where a ball just bounces around the screen. I used classes, lists, and for loops to create more balls that bounce around the screen. I get an error that says `list is not callable`.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import uniform, randrange
import time
#left,top,right,bottom

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=600,height=600)
canvas.pack()

class Ball:#ball characteristics
    def __init__(self,color,size):
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(10,10,50,50,fill="blue")
        self.xspeed = randrange(1,6)
        self.yspeed = randrange(1,6) 
    def move(self):#ball animation
        canvas.move(self.shape,self.xspeed,self.yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[0] <= 0 or pos[2] >= 600:#if ball hits the wall#
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        if pos[1] <= 0 or pos[3] >= 600:
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed
balls = []
for i in range(100):
    balls.append(Ball("red",50))

while True:
    for ball in balls():
        ball.move()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: always put in question full error message (Traceback). There are other usefful linformation.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `balls` but `balls` is a list, and is therefore not callable. Take out the call in:

```
for ball in balls():
    ball.move()
```

It should be:

```
for ball in balls:
    ball.move()
```

In other words, the problem is exactly what the error message said, on exactly the line it said.